# token_for_business for Facebook friends

Tags: facebook, ranking, facebook-friends

I'm making a facebook login and saving user "token_for_business" in my database. Now i'd like to make a friends only ranking. Can I retrieve my facebook friends token_for_business too or should I store their app-scoped IDs on another table and make a friends ranking over there?

Answer (score 0):

You can't use the token_for_business for any other query, just to get the App scope IDs for the same user in different Apps of that business. As you commented, you'll have to store app scope IDs and tokens and query for each one.